# How to add a table between multiple tables in HTML using JQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how to add table in between any two of the table, Currently i'm able to add the table in append mode which is add the table at the end i.e. `<div id="main-div">`!
So there is button in base table in `<tfoot>` is `add table here` if user click on that button table should be added after table on which table button gets clicked.

**For Example** :

> I have created 5 tables out of which i want add one more table after
>   3rd table so if i click on `add table here` button then table should
>   be get added at the 4th position not at the end.
>
> any suggestion ?any solution

```js
var filterTableNum = 0;
$('.add-table').click(add_empty_table);

function add_empty_table() {
    const originTable = document.getElementById('source-table');
    let newTable = originTable.cloneNode(true);
    newTable.id = 'source' + ++filterTableNum;
    newTable.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((element) => {
        element.value = '';
    });
    $(newTable).find('.component-id').val(newTable.id);
    $('#main-div').append(newTable);
    
}

function add_table_between(){

}
```

```css
#container>table{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-table">
        Add Table
      </button>
<div id="container">     
<table
          id="source-table"
          data-component-type="Source"
          class="component-base table table-responsive table-striped rounded"
        >
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="6" class="text-center">
                <span>Source : </span
                ><input
                  id="id"
                  type="text"
                  name="id"
                  placeholder="id"
                  class="component-id form-control-head"
                />
                <button
                  class="delete-component btn btn-danger"
                  style="margin: 1%;"
                >
                  Delete Table
                </button>
              </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Type</th>
              <th scope="row">Name</th>
             
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input
                  id="type"
                  type="text"
                  name="type"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Type"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  id="Name"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Name"
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>    
            <tr>
            <td>
            <button class="btwn-table">Add Table Here</button>
           
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
 <div class="main-div" id="main-div"></div>
```

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/shreekantbatale2/krnpfw36/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`insertAfter`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) for doing this.
Moreover you need to set the event on `document`, since the buttons are not existing on initialization but created dynamically.

```js
var filterTableNum = 0;
$('.add-table').click(add_empty_table);
$(document).on('click', '.btwn-table', add_table_between);

function create_table() {
    const originTable = document.getElementById('source-table');
    let newTable = originTable.cloneNode(true);
    newTable.id = 'source' + ++filterTableNum;
    newTable.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((element) => {
        element.value = '';
    });
    $(newTable).find('.component-id').val(newTable.id);
    return $(newTable);
}

function add_empty_table() {
    let newTable = create_table();
    $('#main-div').append(newTable);
}

function add_table_between(e){
    let newTable = create_table();
    let originTable = $(e.target.closest('table'));
    newTable.insertAfter(originTable);
}
```

```css
#container>table{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-table">
        Add Table
      </button>
<div id="container">     
<table
          id="source-table"
          data-component-type="Source"
          class="component-base table table-responsive table-striped rounded"
        >
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="6" class="text-center">
                <span>Source : </span
                ><input
                  id="id"
                  type="text"
                  name="id"
                  placeholder="id"
                  class="component-id form-control-head"
                />
                <button
                  class="delete-component btn btn-danger"
                  style="margin: 1%;"
                >
                  Delete Table
                </button>
              </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Type</th>
              <th scope="row">Name</th>
             
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input
                  id="type"
                  type="text"
                  name="type"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Type"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  id="Name"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Name"
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>    
            <tr>
            <td>
            <button class="btwn-table">Add Table Here</button>
           
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
 <div class="main-div" id="main-div"></div>
```